# Is it practical to use Mongo's capped collection a memory cache?

Tags: mongodb

Is it practical to use Mongo's capped collections as poor man's memcache assuming it will be kept in memory most of the time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can definitely use capped collections for this purpose. But it's important to know the basic limitations.

1. Data will expire based on insert order not time-to-expire
2. Data that is frequently accessed may still be pushed out of memory
3. `_id` columns are not defined on Capped Collections by default, you will need to ensure those indexes.
4. The objects cannot be modified in a way that changes the size of the object. For example, you *could* increment an existing integer, but you *cannot* add a field or modify a string value on the entry.
5. The capped collections [cannot be sharded](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2654).

Because of #1 & #4 & #5, you are definitely losing some the core Memcache functionality.

There is a long-outstanding JIRA ticket for [TTL-based capped collections](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-211) which is probably exactly what you want.

Of course, the big question in this whole debate is *"where is the extra RAM"*. Many people who use MongoDB as their primary store simply drop Memcache. If you have a bunch of extra RAM sitting around, why not just use it store the actual data instead of copies of that data?

Comment: #5 is a real issue if your data set is very large or if you query/insert at a very high rate.

Comment: #1 Data could be made to expire with TTL  
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: #2 : Data that is not frequently accessed may still be pushed out of memory
I would think this is desirable behavior.

Comment: At the time of this answer, TTL collections were not available. However, the post does include a link to the JIRA ticket for TTL which is now marked as closed.

Comment: @ajeet you are correct about point #2. Corrected on the post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  This is a perfectly acceptable use of a MongoDB capped collection.  I am assuming you will have many more reads than writes, so make sure you use an index as well.

[MongoDB Capped Collections: Applications](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections#CappedCollections-Applications)

Answer (score 1):

As said by Gates VP, capped collections are usable and easy to manage. However you can also use non-capped collections if you :

- have a dedicated server for your "poor's man memcache"
- have a lot of data, which cannot fit on one server (or you want to query very fast)
- are ok with dealing with TTL yourself (just add one field)

MongoDB cache (mmap on Unix-like systems) will provides a "unlimited" memcache, caching frequently accessed values.
As said on the mongo FAQ page :

> The goal is for Mongo to be an alternative to an ORM/memcached/mysql stack